# Electron app Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to implement auth process in my electron app but after loading the page I receive amount of exceptions:
[image: console log]

My code

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600, 
show: false, 'node-integration': false })
mainWindow.loadURL(authUrl);
mainWindow.show();

function handleCallback(url) {

}

mainWindow.webContents.on('will-navigate', function(event, url) {
    handleCallback(url);
})

mainWindow.webContents.on('did-get-redirect-request', function(event, oldUrl, newUrl) {
    handleCallback(newUrl);
})

// Emitted when the window is closed.
mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
    mainWindow = null
})
```

Comment: There's no exports in your code.

Comment: I know but I have not found a way to define them on my app (sorry I am not a JS programmer it's just a supporting project)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved problem by including several modules:

```
const electron = require('electron')
const app = electron.app
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow
const 
const redirectUri = 'your redirect';
let mainWindow

const    qs = require('querystring'),
         shell = require('shell'),
         _ = require('lodash'),
         path = require('path'),
         url = require('url')

 function createWindow() {

var querystring = require('querystring');
var https = require('https');
var clientId = 'your client id';
var scope = ['account-info', 'operation-history', 'operation-details'];
var authUrl = 'https://money.yandex.ru/oauth/authorize?';
var apiUrl = 'https://money.yandex.ru/api';
var authUrl = authUrl + 'client_id=' + clientId +
    '&redirect_uri=' + redirect_uri +
    '&scope=' + scope.join(" ") +
    '&response_type=' + 'code';

let token = null;

authWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    type: 'splash',
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: false
    }
});

authWindow.on('closed', function() {
    authWindow = null;
    resolve(token);
});

authWindow.webContents.on('new-window', function(e, url) {
    e.preventDefault();
    shell.openExternal(url);
});
authWindow.webContents.on('will-navigate', function (event, url) {
     console.log(url);
});

authWindow.webContents.on('did-get-redirect-request', function (event, 
 oldUrl, newUrl) {
console.log(newUrl);
});

authWindow.loadURL(authUrl);
 }


app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
     if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
         app.quit()
     }
 })

app.on('activate', function() { 
     if (mainWindow === null) {
         createWindow()
    }
 })
```

Don't forget about npm install)

Answer (score 3):

`'node-integration': false` disables nodejs features like module import and export with `require` and also the access to nodejs modules like `fs`, `path`, etc and any module from installed via npm/yarn. This is why you are not able to load your module.